# If/Else when spacebar is pressed (C)

Tags: c, if-statement

This C program has to print user's surname and I want to introduce the case of double surnames using IF/Else. 
The condition I thought to use is: "when spacebar is pressed, collect another string". The matter is that I don't know how to define this condition..

this is my code:

```
    printfcognome() {
char cognome[DIM];
char cognome2[DIM];

printf("Inserisci il tuo cognome\n");
scanf("%s", cognome);

    if(???) {
    scanf("%s", cognome2);
    printf("Il tuo cognome è " "%s %s", cognome, cognome2);
    }   else    {
    printf("Il tuo cognome è " "%s", cognome);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to store the last names in two separate variables?/È necessario tenere i cognomi in due variabili separati? Usa `fgets`

Comment: Okay but we haven't still studied that, I just begun my programming course so I'd like to complete this assignment with what we already know.
No it isn't really necessary to use two separate variables but that's what I thought to solve the problem.
How should I use fgets() anyway?

Comment: You should do your homework by your own...

Comment: @Viktor  Check return of `scanf`. Write your condition as follows -`if(scanf("%s", cognome)==1{` then your code to take another input . As soon as you press space bar `scanf` will retrun .

Comment: @IlVic I just asked how to define a condition which I don't know, not to code this from scratch.

Comment: Oh god. Why don't you simpy *read lines*?

Comment: solved with scanf ( "%[^\n]", cognome); I learned about fgets aswell so really appreciated the help!